# Reading data from a file into an array of class objects

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io, split

I'm reading data from a file that I need to be put into my array of objects (myEmployees). I believe my code is correct until the end of this example, but I am not sure how to read the data from the file, split it, and then put it correctly into my array of class objects.

```
//declare an array of employees
Employee[] myEmployees = new Employee[10];

//declare other variables
string inputLine;
string EmpName;
int EmpNum;
double EmpWage;
double EmpHours;
string EmpAdd;

//declare filepath
string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath
(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\";

//get input
Console.Write("\nEnter a file name in My Documents: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string path = environment + input;
Console.WriteLine("Opening the file...");

//read file
StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(path);
inputLine = (myFile.ReadLine());
```

So I am reading data from a file that is structured like:

```
Employee Number
Employee Name
Employee Address
Employee wage Employee Hours
```

I need to read data from this file and parse it into the array of Employees that I've created. Here is the class data for class Employee:

```
public void Employeeconst ()
{
    employeeNum = 0;
    name = "";
    address = "";
    wage = 0.0;
    hours = 0.0;
}
public void SetEmployeeNum(int a)
{
    employeeNum = a;
}
public void SetName(string a)
{
    name = a;
}
public void SetAddress(string a)
{
    address = a;
}
public void SetWage(double a)
{
    wage = a;
}
public void SetHours(double a)
{
    hours = a;
}
public int GetEmployeeNum()
{
    return employeeNum;
}
public string GetName()
{
    return name;
}
public string GetAddress()
{
    return address;
}
public double GetWage()
{
    return wage;
}
public double GetHours()
{
    return hours;
}
```

Comment: @Robert Harvey  What is the reason for deleting my answer. Please let me know so that I will not repeat the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest to redesign your Employee class using properties, which is more readable and better follows principles of object oriented programming:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeNum { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double Wage { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }

    public void Employee()
    {
        EmployeeNum = 0;
        Name = "";
        Address = "";
        Wage = 0.0;
        Hours = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Also consider wrapping StreamReader in '*using*' keyword, which ensures that file will be closed correctly. The rest of program is easy, just read your file line by line until end of file. Parse each line to desired type and set value to Employee object:

```
        using(StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            int index = 0;
            while(!myFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                Employee E = new Employee();
                E.EmployeeNum = Int32.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
                E.Name = myFile.ReadLine();
                E.Address = myFile.ReadLine();
                E.Wage = Double.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
                E.Hours = Double.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
                myEmployees[index++] = E;
            }
        }
```

I did not include eny error checking in my sample code, so it is up to you to do it.

Comment: thanks very much, this is awfully clean code! this is a homework assignment, so i actually have to write separate methods for each get / set, otherwise i would do it using properties. i really like the way you've done the file reading. Edit: answered my own question

Comment: So this code is throwing an exception on the "E.Wage" line, saying that "Input string was not in correct format".

Comment: Since you did not include example of your input, file, I cannot tell what the problem is, but I guess that Wage (and probably Hours too) in your file uses decimal separator character, that doesn't match decimal separator used in your culture. Use overload of Parse method, that accepts CultureInfo as second parameter and provide there appropried CultureInfo object. Something like E.Wage=Double.Parse(myFile.ReadLine(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("Some appropriate culture"));

Comment: I had just used the code you provided. In the file, the "wage" does use a decimal separator. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting reading it line by line

See example here on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

For each line you read you will have a string - you can split this string into an array using string.Split.

```
string mystring = "50305 FirstName LastName 1234 Anywhere Place 133.25 40";
string[] myarray = mystring.Split(' ');
```

I would suggest however handling the string input for doublespaces, etc.

You could do something like this to get rid of duplicate spaces.

```
string mynewstring = mystring.Replace("  ", " ");

while (mynewstring.Contains("  "))
{
  mynewstring = mystring.Replace("  ", " ");
}
```